# how to properly use on_resize function in kivy or kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

In my app i need to call certain function in certain screen when it is resized, and it looks like this

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def on_resize(self):
        if self.manager.get_screen() == "table_screen":   
            if self.width>self.height:
                self.manager.get_screen("table_screen").ids.table_image.source="table1.png"
                self.manager.get_screen("table_screen").ids.left_panel.opacity=0
                print("PAPAPAPPAAPPA")
            else:
                self.ids.left_panel.size_hint_x=.5
                self.ids.left_panel.opacity=1
                print("PAPAPAPPAAPPA")

    def build(self):
        Window.bind(size=self.on_resize)
        return Main()
```

but when i resize window in any screen, the image shatters and i get an error
on_resize() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
what is the origin of this error? I dont see to give 3 argument anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The origin of the error is that when you bind a function to a property change, it receives three positional arguments. They are `self`, the instance of the class instance whose property is changing, and the new value of the property.

Comment: i see now, but i still can not quite understand what to do then, do i just delete self from arguments?

Comment: thanks for help, just added self and *args and it works now